# Power Bi Errorcode: 28- No space left on device

Tags: mysql, database, powerbi

I was testing powerBi for a while a dont get any problems. Now I am doing a huge query, bigger then ever and I got this error while evaluating my data. On my disk I have still over 300 GB of free space. How can I fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem arising from PowerBI Desktop, this is coming from MySQL - further supported by the referenced path of `/var/lib/mysql`... Check the disk on the server where mySQL is running. From a short Google it seems like you should be able to free up some space by purging binary logs which allow point in time recover and replication - remove these before a specific point in time that you are comfortable with. You may be able to perform other maintenance that alleviated disk pressure - or resize the allocation on the MySQL drive / mount.

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss';
```

[More info here](https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/working-with-mysql-binary-logs).

Comment: You mean to check my local disk where file is running or my mysql server disk?

Comment: MySQL - wherever that is running!